# How to track players?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have seen Dream and GeorgeNotFound's videos filming a minecraft manhunt event. I wish to replicate this but i'm not sure how to command a tracking device? In windows 10 edition by the way.

Video Here -

Comment: Track in what way? Please do not rely on external websites that might be changed any moment for understandability. Your question should have all the necessary information contained in it.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way to do this is with one repeating commandblock just enter this command: 
`/execute @e[name=(name of player you are hunting)] ~ ~ ~ /setworldspawn ~ ~ ~`
and your compass will always point to them